# Why does "bob" == "godzilla" in Perl?

Tags: perl, argv

In Perl class today, a student turned in an assignment which vexes me. We are studying ARGV, but the result was not what I expected.  His program (meme.pl) was:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$A = $ARGV[0];
chomp($A);
if ($A == "godzilla"){
    print "$A\n";
}
else {
    print "We need a monster's name\n";
}
```

If I type:

```
% ./meme.pl bob
```

the result is

```
% bob
```

So the variable assignment works, and but the condition ($A == "godzilla") is true no matter what is typed on the command line. I expected that since $ARGV[0] is "bob" and $A=$ARGV[0], then it should not true that $A="godzilla."

What am I missing? I have combed through this code for hours, and I know I am just overlooking some small thing.

Comment: It sounds like your class is not using _Learning Perl_ :)

Comment: If I were teaching a class Perl, I would reject any assignment that doesn't start with `use warnings` and `use strict`.

Answer (score 15):

Use `eq`, not `==`, to test string equality:

```
if ($A eq "godzilla"){
```

More information is available at [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).

**Note:** Adding `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your script would have led you in the right direction.

Answer (score 11):

`use strict;` and `use warnings;` should be on...instant F in my book.

But no...evaluations of strings using "==" evaluate all strings - except those that start with a number like '123bob' (see comment below) - as numerical 0. That is why it is evaluating to true - it's "turning into" the statement `0 == 0`. `use warnings;` would have told you something was up.

As many have said - use `eq` for strings.

More evidence and options can be found here: (http://perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/comparing_values.html)

The pertinent excerpt (example program):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string1 = 'three';
my $string2 = 'five';

if ($string1 == $string2) {
    print "Equal\n";
} else {
    print "Not equal\n";
}
```

From the above example, you would get warning messages and both strings would evaluate to zero:

```
Argument "five" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./test.pl line 8.
Argument "three" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./test.pl line 8.
Equal
```

---

You aren't getting those warnings...just the "Equal", thanks to the absence of `use warnings;` at the top of your - errr...your student's...*cough*... - code. ;)

Comment: Minor correction... Not _all_ strings evaluate as numeric 0. Strings which start with digits will evaluate as that number. e.g., `'123bob' == 123` is true; `'123bob' == 0` is false.

Comment: I'd also add that the string `0 but true` will evaluate to true and not cause a warning when used as a number.

Answer (score 6):

When you are comparing strings, you must use "eq" instead of "==". So replace

```
($A == "godzilla")
```

by

```
($A eq "godzilla")
```

Answer (score 5):

What the others said is correct about using `eq` to compare strings.  However, the test passes, because when compared numerically with `==` the string 'bob' and the string 'godzilla' both evaluate to 0, so the test passes and you get `bob`.

Comment: The numification of a string that doesn't start with digits is always zero. ("123abc" → 123, "abc" → 0)